# supremum of additive functions is additive

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, monoid

I need some help for one equality in the following proposition. It was a hint to conclude that $\sup\{f(\cdot):f\in\Phi\}$ is additive. I highlighted it blue. Ultimately I am interested in proving the proposition, but the main question is a hint with how to obtain the blue equality $\overset{☹}{=}$.

**Proposition.** Let $(X,+,0)$ be an abelian monoid. Let $(M,\preceq, +,0)$ be an ordered monoid. Fix $\Phi\subseteq M^X$. Assume the following.

(i) $(\forall f\in\Phi)[f:(X,+,0)\to (M,+,0)]$

(ii) $(\forall f_1,f_2\in\Phi)(\exists f_3\in\Phi)(\forall x\in X)[f_1(x)\preceq f_3(x)\text{ and }f_2(x)\preceq f_3(x)]$

(iii) $(\forall x\in X)[\sup\{f(x):f\in\Phi\}\text{ exists in }M]$

Then $\sup\{f(\cdot):f\in\Phi\}$ is additive.

hint provided from source material:
For all $x,y\in X$,
$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\sup\{f(x):f\in\Phi\}+\sup\{f(y):f\in\Phi\}}&\overset{\color{blue}☹}=\color{blue}{\sup\{f_1(x)+f_2(y):f_1,f_2\in\Phi\}}\\
&\preceq \sup\{f(x)+f(y):f\in\Phi\}\\
&=\sup\{f(x+y):f\in\Phi\}\\
&\preceq\sup\{f(x):f\in\Phi\}+\sup\{f(y):f\in\Phi\}
\end{align}$$

I can easily show $\succeq$ of $\overset{☹}{=}$, but not the other direction. I believe I am missing something subtle with the assumptions because with **ordered monoids** one has $$\sup S+\sup T\succeq \sup(S+T)\tag{1}$$
when the suprema all exist. In particular, if one considers $(-\infty,+\infty]$ adjoined with $\{n\cdot +\infty\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we have an ordered monoid where if $S=T=\mathbb{R}$, then we get a strict inequality of $(1)$. If instead one considers **ordered groups**, then one can show equality in $(1)$. It is because of this that I somehow believe the proposition should be considering ordered groups instead of ordered monoids, but, again, I may be missing something subtle with the assumptions.

I also want to add I already know how to prove the proposition if I have the blue equality at hand.

Comment: What blue equality?  I didn't know that equalities could get the blues.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I made some edits: $\overset{☹}{=}$

Comment: You have already given a counter example, so assume group.